# Add Checkbox like "Cash on Delivery" in billing method on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment-methods, ce-1.9.2.3

How to create and allow cash on delivery checkbox on billing address step of checkout? If it's enabled then cash on delivery payment method should be visible on payment step.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. This requirement sounds strange but maybe I don't understand it correctly. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do? Why should the customer select the payment method in the billing address step?

Comment: It is Task for me ... i want to put the checkbox on billing address step of checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in  billing.phtml  create Your New Checkbox.
**app\design\frontend\themename\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml**

paste this code..

```
<li class="control">

                    <input type="checkbox" name="cod" value="You-Select-Cash-On-Delivery" title="" id="cod1" onchange="" checked="" class="checkbox" /><label for="">
                    <?php echo $this->__('Cash on Delivery') ?></label>

                    <?php 
                        if(isset($_POST['cod'])){
                                echo "Checked !!!";                             
                                $var = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('cod'); //session store variable
                                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCod($var);
                        }
                    ?>  
                </li>
```

Then Go to methods.phtml

**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml**

Paste This Code

```
<?php $outputMessage =Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCod(); echo $this->__($outputMessage); ?>
```

At Last Go TO OnepageController.phtml

**app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php**

Find saveBillingAction() 
Paste This Code...

```
$var = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('cod');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCod($var);
```

Comment: Great Code!!!!!!!!! It's work for me.....